Common authentication(Azure AD) for multiple ASP.NET MVC web projects
I have a Visual Studio solution with multiple ASP.NET MVC web projects (.NET 4.8) deployed in IIS. In the "home" project, which is the startup project added Azure AD authentication, it works fine.
If try to access pages from other projects, I get an authentication error.
How to implement a common authentication for all the projects? All projects are under the same domain name.

Thanks for response. I implemented same Azure AD settings in startup and webconfig of other project. But still when we hit any controller from that project, it is not going to its startup class and errors out as not authenticated. Please explain about cookie setup, you mean shared cookie?

To use common Azure AD for all the .NET Framework apps, you need to ensure that all the apps are using the same credentials.

Make sure the same configuration is done in all the web.config files.

As per this MSDoc,

Single sign-on is an authentication method that allows users to sign in using one set of credentials to multiple independent software systems.


With SSO, users can access all needed applications without being required to authenticate using different credentials.

To implement a common authentication, you need to use Shared authentication cookies among the Web Apps.

Websites often consist of individual web apps working together. To provide a single sign-on (SSO) experience, web apps within a site must share authentication cookies.

Refer this blog to configure Single Sign-On (SSO) with Microsoft Azure AD
Shared Cookies set up:
Install the below NuGet packages
Microsoft.Owin;
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
Microsoft.Owin.Security;
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection;
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop;
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;


Create a new Start up class file and add the code show in MSDoc.


[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication3.Startup))] 

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Config(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app); 
        }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           ---
           ---
        }
    }
}

